# Electric going out in half of house

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have 3 rooms that lose power on my main floor and 3 that still have power with no breakers being set off.  One of the rooms is the kitchen but the stove still works.  Actually when the power goes off in those 3 rooms and you turn on a stove burner the power immediately comes back on.  I have changed almost all of the sockets in the 3 rooms and it has almost stopped completely but still goes off a few times a day. I have a few more to go and then will get into the breaker box I guess.  Any other advice?

Comment: Sounds like loose connection or a problem with a neutral, both of which could be dangerous. I'd have it checked out very soon if you don't find the problem yourself.

Comment: Is your electric meter (watthour meter) running normally or does it seem to be frozen in time/dead whenever the stove's off?

Comment: Your house is at risk of an electrical fire.  Get this fixed now, call an electrician (or do it yourself, if you think you can do it without killing yourself or your family), but stop using your 240V appliances until the problem is corrected.  Changing outlets randomly is not going to fix this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have lost a phase. Your stove, once switched on, is backfeeding through the phase that isn't working. You are looking for a burnt lug or wiring probably in the meter base or panel. If you can't see any burnt or discoloring, you will need to turn off your stove and then check for voltage at the load side of all of your breakers.

[image]

You're looking for something like this.

Comment: I wouldn't be absolutely confident. We discovered my brother-in-law's house (an electrician to boot) has half the house on one breaker. He knows it's bad but hasn't fixed it.

Comment: And then *test* for voltage - you missed a word.

Comment: @immibis Anyone with positive reputation can suggest an edit to a question or answer (not comment though).  Its totally fine to edit the text, to improve the meaning, clarity or sense.  If you have under 2000 rep in the stack, the edit gets queued for peer review, and you get +2 rep if its accepted from peer review.

Comment: @Criggie: edit suggestions must be substantial, just adding one small word will not be accepted by the system.

Comment: Which is why so many questions network wide remain with typos.

Comment: Will the stove really backfeed through the neutral?  That sounds suspiciously wrong.  The elements are all 240V and wired without a neutral connection.  The only reason the neutral goes to the stove at all is to supply the 120V convenience outlets .  More likely what is happening is that turning on the stove is energizing the dead phase through the coils and creating an arc that completes the circuit at the bad (corroded) connection in the panel.  **This is an extreme fire risk** OP needs to get this sorted out ASAP, and I would suggest not using the stove or other 240V appliances until then.

Comment: @J... I hadn't noticed that. You're right. It wouldn't backfeed through the neutral, it would backfeed through the other side of the phase. The stove should also be working like crap.

Comment: @Spark It may or may not be working like crap.  If the bad connection is so bad that the stove is backfeeding the other outlets then it would certainly be working like crap (and that would be better than the stove mosly working normally).  Otherwise the voltage backfeed could be provoking flashover at the bad connection that actually makes the connection to the dead phase and is overheating the lug (this would be worse - the stove would appear to mostly be working normally).

Comment: @Spark if the first case is true (stove backfeeding other outlets) then there would be low voltage at the (now "working") outlets and the stove would only work in proportion to the load attached at those outlets.  The more load, the hotter the stove, the lower the voltage in the "dead" rooms.  If the voltage in the dead rooms comes up to near normal, however, then the more dangerous flashover situation is more likely the case.  In any event, it is a bad, bad circumstance and it needs to be fixed now.

Comment: @J - Not true your top burner elements will usually use 120V on low temperature settings.

Comment: @RetiredMasterElectrician Element power is duty cycle controlled, usually by a bimetallic thermostat or something similar.  The voltage to the coils doesn't change.  I find that claim also suspicious.

Answer (score 6):

Retired is correct.

I would only add that it is possible the phase has been lost at the Service or even on the pole.  If a licensed (if you live in a licensed state) or at least qualified electrician puts a meter on the load side of the main breaker and finds a lost phase, but finds the expected phases coming in from the meter, then the problem is inside your house.  If there aren't 240 volts coming in from the meter, then your problem is in the meter or at the pole.

Either way, you'll probably need to get your local utility involved.