# Why are some of the outlets and light circuits out in my home?

Tags: electrical

So I'm in the dark...literally. All the switches/overhead fixtures are out and most of the outlets in the house as well. So, I do have a few outlets working in different parts of the house. 
I have checked the breaker, starting visually, nothing looks tripped. So, starting with the sub breakers, I turned them all off from left to right and back on from right (main) to left. Nothing changed. And I did really push hard off and push hard on. No change. This happened in the middle.of the night Easter Saturday, so no services available until today.

Could this be the Electric company's issue, or should I just call an electrician? I did call Edison and I am waiting for them to show up....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Electric going out in half of house](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/119575/electric-going-out-in-half-of-house)

Comment: Sounds like you lost a phase of power. The electric company should be able to fix that.

Comment: Is there any pattern as to which circuits work and which have failed? Do any 240V appliances (range, water heater, dryer) work or partially work?

Answer (score 2):

### This is an outage.  Call the electric company.

They should respond *immediately, 24x7, and for free*... unless coincidentally it's right after an ice storm or windstorm that clobbered power to thousands of your district's customers.

If you're going "I can't, it's the weekend and the office is closed until Monday" - wrong office.  Every power company has an emergency number to report downed wires 24x7.  That number is entirely appropriate for reporting outages.  Yes, they do keep a bucket truck and crew warmed up 24x7 because wires go down, and *that* can't wait.   Our PoCo sent one out on a Sunday afternoon, and I stuck around to run around and notify neighbors and shut main breakers.

Sometimes the problem is inside your service panel, and the PoCo doesn't fix that... but odds are what changed is outdoors, and thus, in their wheelhouse. Service panels don't have weather inside them.